# c# jtoken select token

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to grab a url value from a json using JSON.net and jtoken SelectTokens method, I'm able to get the label for the url from the json but not able to get the url value.

This is a part of the json from which I'm trying to grab the url. I'm trying to get the label "Law Library " and its corresponding "href"

```
"anchorEndControls": [
    {
      "State": {
        "clickAction": 19,
        "image": "$$USERDATA$$Toolbars\\images\\Comm.png",
        "showLabel": true,
        "label": "Commissary ",
        "href": "https://deposits.com",
        "favicon": false
      },
      "type": 2,
      "mergeStyles": []
    },
    {
      "State": {
        "clickAction": 19,
        "image": "$$USERDATA$$Toolbars\\images\\Law.png",
        "showLabel": true,
        "label": "Law Library",
        "href": "https://apps.com",
        "favicon": false
      },
      "type": 2,
      "mergeStyles": []
    },


public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


       var list1 = jObj.SelectTokens("$.....State.*")
       .Where(t => t.Value<string>() == labeltofind).ToList()


        foreach (var item in list1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

As you can see I am able to get the label "Law Library " but not able to get the corresponding href

Comment: Your question will be easier to answer if your example was complete and we could check it for ourselves. Please have a look at how to provide an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method gets you the information of each of the lists based on your input.

```
   string labelToFind = "Commissary ";
   var list1 = jObj.SelectTokens($"anchorEndControls[?(@.State.label == '{labelToFind}')]").ToList();
```

**Alternate Suggestion**

Linq is another solution i can suggest since you can use queries to get specific items from your json and get corresponding values. You can get the classes for the json you are using from any of the websites such as www.json2csharp.com.

```
    public class State
    {
        public int clickAction { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public bool showLabel { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public bool favicon { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnchorEndControl
    {
        public State State { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public List<object> mergeStyles { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<AnchorEndControl> anchorEndControls { get; set; }
    }
```

**Usage**

1. Deserialize the object to the root class (based on the root element of your json)
2. Find the element that has the Label you are looking for
3. Use that element to look up corresponding href value.

```
    var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var element = jsonObj.anchorEndControls.Where(x => x.State.label.Equals("Law Library")).First();
    Console.WriteLine(element.State.href);
```

**Output**

```
https://apps.com
```

Comment: How does this explain the issue the OP is having?

Comment: I understand this is an alternative solution, not what the OP is working with. It would be helpful to explain what the OP did wrong so they can *see** why it happened.

Comment: This worked, Thank you so much for your help!!!! I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Jawad Thank you, I just marked your solution as my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are diving in too deep with that `.Where()` clause, it will filter out all the properties except `Label`. Here's a way to do it:

```
foreach (JToken state in jObj.SelectTokens("$.....State"))
{
    if (state["label"].ToString() == labeltofind)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(state["href"]);
    }  
}
```